# Creating a string from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, directory

Actually I have this list "Directory" where I am adding the name of the project as string.

index 0
oldProjectName Project 1

index 1
oldProjectName Project 2

I want to create a string like this /project1/project2/, to create a directory path but I have a problem when I create it .

```
 foreach (string s in Directory)
            {                    
                DirectoryPath = '/' + DirectoryPath + '/' + thePreviousItem.oldProjectName + '/';
            }
```

I am wondering why the result is always /Project1/project2/project2/ ...

Comment: You're not using `s` in your loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try

 DirectoryPath=""
foreach (string s in Directory)
        {

            DirectoryPath = DirectoryPath.equals("")?  s : '/' + DirectoryPath + '/' + s + '/';
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

why not:

```
DirectoryPath = string.Join(@"/", Directory);
```